# I am getting an "Invalid Host header" message when connecting to my domain (on AWS PM2 machine with Nginx)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, nginx, pm2

Our application is running on AWS we can access it using public IP, however when we try to connect our react app with such as `my.domian.com` i am getting invalid header error.

I tried adding `HOST = mydomain.com` to the .env file but it didn't work.anyone have any ideas or help?

Comment: Are you trying to connect react app from local or remote host? Is there anything in logs?

Comment: I am trying to connect from remote host , there is no error

Comment: Where did you get `invalid header error` then? Could you show exact error data?